# Using the return json code

Tags: ajax, json, associative-array, jquery-post

I'me trying to use ajax with php, I have the follogin script in php :

```
<?php

// this file get the POST infor sent by a AJAX request and will return the value is succesful.

$price['name'] = "Called";
$price['Wheel']  = 75.25;
$price['Tire']   = 50.00;

echo json_encode($price);
?>
```

and I'm calling this code from my main page in the following way :

```
        $.post("ajax/profileMod.php", {
            'lname':lname,
            'fname':fname,
            'mname':mname,
            'language':language,
            'title':title,
            'ptype':ptype,
            'vip':vip,
            'vreason':vreason
        })
        // Retreive the data from the php script
        .done(function(data) {
         // php code : echo json_encode(array("name"=>"Called!"));
            alert(data);
        }, "json");

        // Stop original behavior
        return false;
    });
```

The returniong result from the alert is the following test : 
{"name":"Called",Wheel":75.25,"Tire":50}

How can I change this result so I may use it in the following way in javascript EX:

alert(myresult['Name']) ; Would give me "Called".

So I basicly would like a associative array in javascript, but I read somewhere on this forum that you can't have associative array in Javascript, only object...

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `"json"` as the last parameter to `.post()` to tell jQuery to parse the response as JSON.
(or, fix your server to return the correct `Content-Type` of `application/json`, and jQuery should do that automatically)

You will then get a Javascript object, allowing you to write

```
alert(result.name);
```

Comment: When I do so, and change the alert to "alert(data.name)" in my code I get the response "Undefined".

Comment: @DanielBerthiaume: Call `console.log(data)` and look at the console.

Comment: What's the actual response body?

Comment: In the body I get the alert box saying "Undefined". Since the actual data variable contains {"name":"Called",Wheel":75.25,"Tire":50}. Is the a way I can parse it manually?

Comment: I've finally made it! I've used the following code : var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);alert(obj.name); and it work!!! Thank you for your help! But I did whish I could had nice code to do so!

Comment: You don't need to use `parseJSON` if you give a third argument of `'json'` to `$.post`, as stated in the answer. Or set the `Content-type` using `header()` in the PHP.

Comment: I tried placinc the 'json' argument, but then my code froze. I wrote it this way : ' 'vreason':vreason}, 'json') ' but it didn't work, where or how should I place it?